# MMDDYY to YYYYMMDD SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field [Privacy Notice] that is `varchar(50)` and the field has a `MMDDYY` format.I want to convert it to `YYYYMMDD`.

How do I do this?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a large box was displayed that suggested that you add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as the syntax and functionality differs between them. Why did you choose to ignore that suggestion? You're wasting both your time by delaying an answer and that of those who do answer only to find out it won't work for you because you're using a different DBMS. Please [edit] your post and add that tag now. We're happy to help, but you have to do your part first by providing the necessary details (especially when specifically asked to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Use substring to extract the parts and shuffle the year,month,day and convert.

```
select CONVERT(varchar, 
               CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT([Privacy Notice],2)+LEFT([Privacy Notice],2)+SUBSTRING([Privacy Notice],3,2)),
               112)
```

[image]